# multiple target patterns” Makefile error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I am trying to build the linux kernel for arm based i.mx6 board.
I have following these steps for building linux kernel

1.`export ARCH=arm`

2.`export CROSS_COMPILE=/media/cascademic-101/D:/alam/MyProjects/IIOT-Gateway/porting/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

3.`make`

But I am getting the following error.

`Makefile:129: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`

Any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Is this the full output of `make` or only the last line? Does your directory in step 2 have special characters in it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711394/3792138 suggests that e.g. `:` can be a problem.

Comment: yes this is the full output of make

`Makefile:129: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`

Comment: @johnLate yes the Path to the directory for cross-compile contains `:`

Comment: Can you try renaming those directories to not contain any colon (`:`)? Please report back if that works.

Comment: @johnLate yes it works ...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CROSS_COMPILE` must be set to the prefix used for the compiler, not the directory containing it; typically for a 32-bit ARM build,

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

You must then ensure that the corresponding tools are on your `PATH`.

Comment: OK, so you need to export `CROSS_COMPILE` as in my answer, and add `/home/cascademic/quectel/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin` to your `PATH`.